# fade out video's audio after scroll down

Tags: javascript, audio, scroll

My site put a auto play video banner with audio on top, the audio auto play after loaded and start with the video. But I would like to make the audio fade out when user scroll down the page(for example 2000). Because there are other videos at the lower part.

I am studying about the audio feature, and find here are some great reference.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElm = $('#scrollaudio').get(0);
    audioElm.play();

    var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        audioElm.volume = 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / height;
        console.log(audioElm.volume);
    });
});
```

https://codepen.io/envira/pen/AuGKh

but this reference, have to scroll to the botton to make audio totally off , how to make it fade off if,for example, 2000px scrolled down?

Anyone Could help, please? (sorry for my bad grammar.)